# How do I call method in RemoteServiceServlet from HttpServlet?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

I am using **GWT** and want to be able to invoke the method `incrementProduct(String productName)` in my main RemoteServiceServlet by typing this URL in my browser:

`http://mywebshop.appspot.com/increment?name=pillow`

To handle this request I've created the following HttpServlet:

```
public class IncrementServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("IncrementServlet called!");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        // Call MyRemoteServiceServlet.incrementProduct(name) somehow
    }
}
```

and added this to web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>IncrementServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>x.y.z.IncrementServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IncrementServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/increment</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

- **Question 1**: Is this a sensible approach?
- **Question 2**: How do I go about invoking incrementProduct() from the HttpServlet?

Comment: what is WebshopServerImpl?

Comment: WebshopServerImpl is my main RemoteServiceServlet. GWT automatically names the class <Project Name>ServerImpl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to overlook one important fact that solved my problem:

- RemoteServiceServlet **inherits** HttpServlet **!**

So I simply implemented doGet() in my RemoteServiceServlet like this:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    switch (req.getServletPath()) {
    case "/increment":
        incrementProduct(req.getParameter("name"));
        break;
    }
}
```

And replaced IncrementServlet in web.xml with this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/increment</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Which allows me to invoke incrementProduct(...) by entering this URL in a browser:

`http://mywebshop.appspot.com/increment?name=pillow`

which is exactly what I wanted! There simply was no need for *another* HttpServlet :)

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1** In general as an classic servlet code this is fine. As GWT application it does not use anything from GWT.

**Question 2** GWT will generate all the servlet code, you do not have to wrap it inside another servlet(IncrementServlet). To turn this into a GWT application you have to implement AsyncCallback on client side entry point(onModuleLoad()) and on server side you must implement RemoteServiceServlet as you did already, what's missing now is the binding part - an interface definition extending RemoteService with a method having similar signature as your service method. Normally GWT plugin in any IDE would generate the binding part, if not then you can do it manually. See GWT documentation with step by step guide. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication

Note that async rpc is a bit old and has some drawbacks. GWT now has RequestFactory concept, but for your use case I would say it is a big overhead.

Comment: Can methods in a RemoteServiceServlet only be called from the client? I specifically want to call it with a URL in a browser, you see.

Comment: You can call RemoteServiceServlet, but that would mean that you have to inject one servlet instance into another(as in your example). Also this would mean that you have to simulate gwt request as a post action with encoded payload, this is again not a very good practice. 

For your situation I would suggest to map gwt servlet on 2 paths: one as gwtRPC and another as increment servlet. Then inside the servlet you can override doGet and doPost. If needed you can check relativePath and in case of gwt request just call super, incase of url call increment.

Comment: If you use approach which I suggested in previous comment, you can even avoid checking of path, since gwt uses POST, but simple url request will be GET.